# What's wrong with string?

Tags: sql-server

I tried to compose a string to execute in SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000) =
'EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''MS_Description'', @value=N''' + 'описание' + ''', @level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N''' + 'rudata_r2' + ''', @level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N''' + 'Subscriptions' + ''', @level2type=N''COLUMN'',@level2name=N''' + 'id' + '''' + char(13) + char(10) + 'GO'

EXEC(@sql)
```

but I got an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `GO` is **not** a SQL statement - just leave it out

Comment: Thanks. I need to write DDL script with create tables via exec sql. Is this not need GO statement?

Comment: You just plain **cannot have** `GO` in your dynamic SQL - because it's ***NOT*** a SQL statement. Period. If you need to execute several pieces of T-SQL dynamically, you need to use several separate strings and execute them separately. `GO` is a *batch separator* used by SSMS (and e.g. `sqlcmd`) - but it's **NOT** SQL !

Comment: marc_s, thank you very much for knowleges. I will use it in the future.

Comment: Note that this *particular* piece of code makes no sense to execute dynamically, since all it does is call `sp_addextendedproperty` but interpolate the parameter values into a string. Not only is this needlessly more complicated because you need to take care of escaping strings, but as you're executing a stored procedure which is inherently parameterized you can simply do that directly: `sp_addextendedproperty ..., @value=@description, ... @level0name = @schema, ...` and then set variables to the appropriate values instead of building a string.

Comment: The statement terminator in SQL is a semi-colon, which can be used to separate multiple statements in dynamic SQL.  You could change the GO to a semi-colon and follow that by other statements.

Comment: Aside... when using the `EXEC (@string_variable)` pattern and the string variable contains international characters you really should be using `nvarchar` data types. i.e.: `DECLARE @sql varchar(4000) = ... + 'описание' + ...` is likely to break the Cyrillic characters in most database collations, replacing each one with a `?` character, so use `nvarchar(4000)` and `N'описание'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks big to all. I have fixed the problem by changed GO to semicolon. Thanks again